# Отображение веб версии на мобильном в Яндекс.Приложении

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Недавно сделал адаптивную верстку сайта trueanone.com для всех браузеров и разрешений экранов и все работает прекрасно. За исключением Яндекс.Приложения, когда перехожу оттуда на сайт, отображается веб версия. Пробовал писать в техподдержку, может это у них баг (адаптивность настраивал с @media в css). Я уже подумал может приложение не читает стили - хотя это странно. В общем не могу понять  в чем проблема, кто знает, подскажите пожалуйста. 
Прилагаю скрины отображения сайта в обычном браузере и в яндекс.приложении.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для тех кто столкнулся с такой же проблемой, вот решение: нужно было добавить этот мета тег

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Судя по всему, браузер который используется в Яндекс.Приложении либо устарел, либо используется облегченная версия, поэтому ему нужно указывать явно `viewport`. Нашёл я это тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859336/why-are-my-css3-media-queries-not-working